# Evaluating expression in ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

My Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.expr = "Test"
});
app.controller('Test', function ($scope) {
  $scope.HELLO = "HEllo World";
});
```

My Mark Up

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="{{expr}}">{{HELLO}}</div>
</body>
```

This does not work.The documentation says that ng-controller can evaluate expressions.What am I doing wrong ?

[JSBIn Link](http://jsbin.com/ubevel/13/edit)(http://jsbin.com/ubevel/13/edit)

Comment: what is use case for needing to do this? Likely other ways to accomplish needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour and a clearer reading of the docs further clarifies it:

> Name of a globally accessible constructor function or an expression that on the current scope evaluates to a constructor function.

Hence, one can either use a string, or one can use an expression which returns a constructor for the controller, but not an expression which returns a string which is the name of the controller.

As to how to make it work, Maxim has already largely answered your question: by making the `expression` return a constructor for the controller.

Answer (score 6):

Write controller as function (not as `app.controller('Test'`)

Change JS to:

```
var app = angular.module('Demo', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.expr = Test;
});

function Test($scope) {
     $scope.HELLO = "HEllo World";
}
```

And HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="expr">{{HELLO}}</div>
</body>
```

Demo <kbd>[JS BIn](http://jsbin.com/ubevel/15/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Whats wrong with declaring it as controller? I generally declare it as active_new_app.controller('newActiveOrdersCountCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'newActiveOrdersCountModel',
        function($scope, $rootScope, newActiveOrdersCountModel){

            $scope.count_data =  newActiveOrdersCountModel;
        }]); The benefits of this format gets lost

Comment: who did tell you that you lose  benefits? see this JSBin, I added factory: http://jsbin.com/ubevel/19/edit

Comment: when Test($scope, helloWorldFromFactory) will be minified....helloWorldFromFactory, will be changed to something else it can no longer identify the factory .

Comment: What is the Div ng-controller="expr" for?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid `expr` is scope value

Comment: Thanks +1 I am using this

Comment: updated your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cowaruboba/edit?html,css,js,output this works for me